# How can I extract something specific using Jsoup?

Tags: android, json, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

How can I extract the full names from this sample HTML code? 
I only want to get the following.

**Full name1**

**Full name2**

**Full name3**

```
<div class="readerP">
                                            <p><a href="link1_english.html"  title="Complete" >Full name1</a><br>[ other info ]</br> </p>
                                            </di                                        
<div class="readerP">
                                            <p><a href="link2_english.html"  title="Complete" >Full name2</a><br>[ other info ]</br> </p>
                                            </div>
<div class="readerP">
                                            <p><a href="link1_english.html"  title="Complete" >Full name3</a><br>[ other info ]</br> </p>
                                            </div>
```

I am using this code, but it looks to all the 'a' tags in the page, so I would get extra info like.

**Home Page**

**About**

**Contact**

**Full name1**

**Full name2**

**Full name3**

and so on ...

```
  try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.somesite.com").get();
         Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
         for (Element el : links) {
             linkText = el.ownText();

             arr_linkText.add(linkText);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I look at the '**div**' tag and if **class="readerP"** look at the '**a**' tags inside the '**div**'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I look at the 'div' tag and if class="readerP" look at the 'a'
>   tags inside the 'div'?

Using the appropiate selector, in stead of just searching by tags.

```
Elements links = doc.select("div .readerP a");
```

Read more about selectors in the [Jsoup documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Comment: It didn't work. I updated my thread, please take a look at it.

Comment: Check my post carefully because there was an update before that. You have to use the 'select' method, not 'getElementsByTag'.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please check the doc link, jsoup is really powerful and with selectors you can do a lot, it's quite important to learn how to use them properly when working with jsoup.